# Appcelerator not creating apk

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Appcelerator Studio build 4.4.0.201511241829 says packaging successful when i try to sign an apk with my distribution key. However, no .apk file is created in the destination folder. The yellow prompt on Appcelerator that says click here to show in file system does absolutely nothing.

Is anyone else having this issue? I google'd the issue and apparently there was an answer, but since Appcelerator decided to remove all of their forum/answers, I can't read it...

Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: You can still use the google cache to look up some of the old pages. But it would be useful if you add the compilation log. Are you using appc studio or the command line tools? When you run 'appc info' from the command line you get some useful output too. Perhaps some Anrdoid/Java stuff is missing

Comment: You can also visit https://archive.appcelerator.com to find old answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but doing a clean then package fixes this.

Comment: Mark your answer as response and close the issue please =)

Answer (score 0):

An outdated liferayBeacon module(version 0.3) is what caused this for me. I removed it and was able to build an apk.

Using titanium sdk 6.1.0

Comment: Can you please be more specific in your answer? Which module, which versions: the outdated and the good one.